# In a JavaFX 2.x ListView how to get which row is under the mouse?

Tags: javafx-2

The default styling highlights the row the mouse is over. I need to find out which row index that is in an onMouseMove handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the way is to use cell factories. For example consider the sample code in oracle's tutorial here [Example 12-4 Creating a Cell Factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm#CEGIIDDC). To add the functionality you want replace the cell factory setting code as follows:

```
list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
        final ListCell cell = new ColorRectCell();
        cell.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("index: " + cell.getIndex());
            }
        });
        return cell;
    }
});
```